# Use jquery datatable in angular6

Tags: datatable, angular7

I am new to angular and i want to implement jquery datatable in my project.When i implement in a demo project it working perfectly but when i implement on my working project it shows an error,below is my codes

my angular.json file

here i add

```
  "styles": [ 
          "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css",             
          "src/styles.css"              
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
       "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"              
        ],
```

i create a module as admin under this module i create a component as manage-blogs and in tis component i bind dynamic data in table.

my index.html file

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Admin Panel</title>
  <base href="/">
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, 
  user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
  <app-root></app-root>
  <!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
 <script src="assets/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
 <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->

 <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
 <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

my manage-blogs-component.ts file

```
import { Component,ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BlogService } from '../../services/blog.service';
import { Blog } from '../../models/blog';
declare var $;

@Component({
 selector: 'app-manage-blogs',
 templateUrl: './manage-blogs.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./manage-blogs.component.css']
})
export class ManageBlogsComponent implements OnInit {


title = 'Manage Blogs';
blogs: Blog;
error: string;

@ViewChild('dataTable') table;
dataTable: any;

constructor(private blogService: BlogService) { }

ngOnInit():void { 
this.dataTable = $(this.table.nativeElement);
this.dataTable.DataTable();

this.blogService.getBlogs().subscribe(
  (data: Blog) => this.blogs = data,
  error => this.error = error
);

}
}
```

my manage-blog-component.html file

```
    <div class="box-body">
          <table #dataTable class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#ID</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Created At</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let blog of blogs">
                    <td>{{blog.id}}</td>
                    <td><img src="{{blog.image}}" ></td>
                    <td>{{blog.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{blog.created_at | date: 'mediumDate'}}</td>
                    <td class="action">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn- 
                    sm">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

          </table>
          {{error}}
        </div>
```

when i load the page it shows an error 
ERROR TypeError: this.dataTable.DataTable is not a function
But in another demo project i put avove code on app.component file it working.